# How To Handle Incorrect CLLocation Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm developing a fitness tracking app like Runtastic, Nike+ etc. I'll be mapping the entire activity from start to finish. I don't start updating location changes when the app launches, instead I'm starting when the user starts a workout. But when the locationManager start updating, first 3 to 5 CLLocations are very incorrect. Up to a kilometer in errors. I'm using the following code to initialize the location manager:

```
self.locationManager = [(PFAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] locationManager];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5.0;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And in the locationManagerDidUpdateToLocation method:

```
 if( didFindGPS == NO )
 {
     if( [[lastLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow] < 10.0 )
     {
         if( [lastLocation horizontalAccuracy] < 20)
         {
            didFindGPS = YES;
         }
     }
 }
 else
 {
     //process data here
 }
```

This doesn't filter out those first incorrect locations. I've also tried ignoring locations that have horizontalAccury values that are smaller than 20, but then the app doesn't process any locations.

What can be done to improve the first locations or to handle the first incorrect ones?

Comment: Please increase distanceFilter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if ([lastLocation horizontalAccuracy] < 20)...
```

to

```
if (([lastLocation horizontalAccuracy] > 0) && ([lastLocation horizontalAccuracy] < 20))...
```

According to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW5)

> A negative value indicates that the location’s latitude and longitude
>   are invalid.

A negative value of `horizontalAccuracy` that is.

If you want to set the condition for processing data (seems like you do) you should rewrite the code to:

```
if (([lastLocation horizontalAccuracy] > 0) && ([lastLocation horizontalAccuracy] < 20))
{
    didFindGPS = YES;
    //process the data here... since here the location fits your limitations
    //and you don't loose the first location (as in original code)
}
else
{
    didFindGPS = NO;
}
```

Note that this code can give you some false alarms for loosing the GPS so you might want to omit the else block.

Comment: I've tried it and the first location updates are still 300+ meters off the correct location.

Comment: Well yes, because you are processing data outside the conditional block. Your method will get all the locations that pass the filter. But you can still add conditions of your own before processing the data. At this time your if sentences apply only to setting `didFindGPS = YES;`.

Comment: Shouldn't the new location updates be less erroneous than the first ones?

Comment: It all depends on the GPS conditions. Let's say you have your phone in your hands when waiting for initial position fix. Then you put it in your pocket and go running trough forest - accuracy will vary. You can also loose the GPS fix if the current conditions (visibility of the sky, cloud coverage...) are bad enough.

Comment: I'll have to test this further. If I use the if-else statement you've said, when the user has a bad coverage in the start their start position will be lost. I'll test it out in a place covered with buildings later on.

Comment: In your place i would record all the location data (in `CLLocation` form) and later decide what data to display and what not. Sometimes interpolation comes in handy using the not-accurate-enough locations as reference points. Good luck!